# How to open a bootstrap tabs using a link?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have following bootstrap tabs code which is working when I click on the tab but I want to open the tab when I click on a link which I have created using `ul > li > a`

but unfortunately it's not working. how can i do this?

**html code:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.htm#tab1">tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.htm#tab2">tab2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
    <div class="tabbable">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                <p>I'm in Section 2.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Js Code:**

```
<script>
// Javascript to enable link to tab
var hash = document.location.hash;
var prefix = "tab_";
if (hash) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href='+hash.replace(prefix,"")+']').tab('show');
}

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash.replace("#", "#" + prefix);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your `<ul>` a class name, like `alt-nav-tabs`, and then copy the existing navigation JS code. It would look something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Add class to your <ul> element -->
<ul class="alt-nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="index.htm#tab1">tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.htm#tab2">tab2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
    <div class="tabbable">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                <p>I'm in Section 2.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
// Javascript to enable link to tab
var hash = document.location.hash;
var prefix = "tab_";
if (hash) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href='+hash.replace(prefix,"")+']').tab('show');
}

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash.replace("#", "#" + prefix);
});

// Copied (modify class selector to match your <ul> class): Change hash for page-reload
$('.alt-nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash.replace("#", "#" + prefix);
});
</script>
```

---

**Persistent tab visibility:**

Based on the following comment, you have a tab that is showing no matter which tab is active...

> one my give link I see that on a random tab a class called tab-visible
>   is added automatically.

To resolve this, you can use the following code to remove this class after the HTML loads:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tab-bem-estar-e-ambiente').removeClass('tab-visible');
});

</script>
```

Place this script in the `<head>` section, and you should be good to go!

**Alternatively...**

I noticed you tried to override the original `tab-visible` behavior. As it is now, the tab with the `tab-visible` class will *never* be visible, even when that tab is clicked on and active. If you never intend to use the `tab-visible` class on your tabs, you could just remove the style from the original CSS document here:

http://futura-dev.totalcommit.com/wp-content/themes/futura-child/style.css?ver=4.9.8

Find that CSS file in your hosted files, search for `.tab-visible`, and simply remove the class.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately it's not open the tab when I click on the link

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .nav-tabs a[href=#tab2]`

Comment: Try changing your `href="index.htm#tab1"` to just `href="#tab1"`, and do the same for tab2.

Comment: I have found a solution and implemented here: http://futura-dev.totalcommit.com/categorias/#tab-bem-estar-e-ambiente but I see last tab content is always showing. do you know why?

Comment: can you tell me why the other content is still visible?

Comment: one my give link I see that on a random tab a class called `tab-visible` is added automatically.

Comment: Remove the `tab-visible` class from the third tab (`tab-bem-estar-e-ambiente` tab) and that should solve the issue.

Comment: I didn't add this class. It's automatically added, thats strange!!

Comment: I updated my answer, please give this a try and let me know if it works...

Comment: See my recent update, I think you want to remove that `tab-visible` class from your source CSS file located at `wp-content/themes/futura-child/style.css?ver=4.9.8`.

Comment: That class is being added because you are calling out that tag in the URL [futura-dev.totalcommit.com/categorias/#tab-bem-estar-e-ambiente](futura-dev.totalcommit.com/categorias/#tab-bem-estar-e-ambiente). For example, if you go to [http://futura-dev.totalcommit.com/categorias/#tab-cultura](http://futura-dev.totalcommit.com/categorias/#tab-cultura), you'll see that the `cultura` has the `tab-visible` class instead. Something is just preventing the class from being removed when you click on another tag...