# How to select element of click element parents using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following HTML code and I am calling ajax using click event using this class `.educacao_search`.

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-educacao">
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4>EucaÇÃo</h4>
            <ul class="list-inline three">
                <li><a class="educacao_search" data-slug="ension">Ensino</a></li>
                <li><a class="educacao_search" data-slug="enem">ENEM</a></li>
                <li><a class="educacao_search" data-slug="escolas">Escolas</a></li>
                <li><a class="educacao_search" data-slug="lingua-e-linguagens">Lingua e Linguagens</a></li>
                <li><a class="educacao_search" data-slug="historia">História</a></li>
                <li><a class="educacao_search" data-slug="todos">Todos</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback has-search">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="do_search_educacao">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row"><div class="show_result"></div><br></div>
</div>
```

now I on success I want to show result in `show_result` class.

To do this I am using collowing jQuery code but it seems not working! I mean the result is not showing in this class called `show_result`

```
$(this).parents(".tab-pane").find(".show_result").html(result);
```

**Note:** this is a bootstrap tabs and there are 5 tabs with same classes which is `educacao_search` and `show_result`

**Update:**

**Ajax Call:**

```
$(".educacao_search").click(function () {                        
    var slug = $(this).data('slug');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: urls.ajax_url,
        data: {
            'slug': slug,
            'action': 'get_post_content'
        }, success: function (result) {
            $(this).parents(".tab-pane").find(".show_result").html(result);
            //$(this).find(".show_result").html(result);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `.parents(".tab-pane")` sure you want to grab *all* parents? If not, use `.closest(".tab-pane")` instead.

Comment: The problem is the usage of "this" inside the success function, the solution is the "context" parameter. From documentation: `$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `var obj = $(this);` before `.ajax` and use it inside `success` callback.

```
$(".educacao_search").click(function () {                        
    var slug = $(this).data('slug');
    var obj = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: urls.ajax_url,
        data: {
            'slug': slug,
            'action': 'get_post_content'
        }, success: function (result) {
            obj.parents(".tab-pane").find(".show_result").html(result);
            //$(this).find(".show_result").html(result);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

It's important to know how `this` keyword works in javascript. Refer below links it will be helpful.

1. https://javascript.info/object-methods
2. https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/javascript-this-4-rules-7354abdb274c

Comment: You should use the `context` parameter to do that, but this example may work too.

Comment: @Karan Awesome. It seems working but why you create var `obj`?

Comment: @creativeartbd the context of the inner function `success` is different from the context of the outer function `click`, so when you use the keyword `this` you are referencing the wrong object. Declaring a variable in a higher level scope (like `obj` in @karan's example) does the trick.

Comment: When you use `this` inside `success` callback it will refer to different object. So what we can do is declare it outside of `ajax` and use that object inside ajax. You can try `console.log(this)` before ajax call and inside `success`. You will see that both objects will be different.

Comment: Awesome. I understand now :=)

Comment: @Karan can you help me one more bootstrap tabs issue?

Comment: Well,  It's my website: http://futura-dev.totalcommit.com. Here you can see on the first menu I have drop down menu and it's has sub menu. Now when you click on drop down menu or it's sub menu it's should go to corresponding bootstrap tabs panel but it's not. It's only work when you go to that page where I have applied the bootstrap tabs. Its should open the corresponding tab from any location of the URL.

Comment: Sorry man, I don't really get what the issue is. Also without sufficient data about your script and HTML it will not possible to solve issue. It's better you try it out your own.

Comment: you can check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304960/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-tabs-using-a-link/53305148?noredirect=1#comment93494844_53305148